# best way to implement a seeker in gtk for vlc

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, vlc, libvlc

I'm making a video streaming application in python using vlc and gtk. I've tried using the gtk.scale to seek the position for the video, and update its own position accordingly, but it seems like the scale is meant for setting values rather than showing something like time in a smooth animation. I feel like there is a better way to do this, I just don't know how.

```
show_titles = ['']


base_url = 'https://www.watchcartoononline.com/anime/'


chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options);

# uses random.choice to pick a random episode from a random title in show_titles[]
def get_src_of_rand_video():
    _url = base_url+random.choice(show_titles)
    uClient = uReq(_url) 
    page_soup = soup(uClient.read(), "html.parser")
    uClient.close()
    episodes = page_soup.select("div.cat-eps a.sonra")
    link = random.choice(episodes).get('href')
    #get video source
    driver.get(link)
    iframes = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')
    driver.switch_to.frame(1)
    src = driver.find_element_by_id('video-js').find_element_by_tag_name('source').get_attribute('src')
    return src

class ApplicationWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Python-Vlc Media Player")
        self.player_paused=False
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.connect("destroy",Gtk.main_quit)
        self.isFullscreen = False

    def show(self):
        self.show_all()

    def position_changed(self, adj):
        self.player.set_position(0.01*self.positioner.get_value())

    def setup_objects_and_events(self):
        self.connect("key-press-event",self._key_press_event)
        self.playback_button = Gtk.Button()
        self.stop_button = Gtk.Button()
        self.update_button = Gtk.Button()
        #scale for seeking video position
        self.positioner = Gtk.Scale(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL,
         adjustment=Gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0))
        self.positioner.set_digits(0)
        self.positioner.set_hexpand(True)
        self.positioner.set_valign(Gtk.Align.END)
        self.positioner.connect("value-changed", self.position_changed)

        self.play_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-play",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.pause_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-pause",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.stop_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-stop",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.update_image = Gtk.Image.new_from_icon_name(
                "gtk-media-update",
                Gtk.IconSize.MENU
            )
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
        self.stop_button.set_image(self.stop_image)
        self.update_button.set_image(self.update_image)


        self.playback_button.connect("clicked", self.toggle_player_playback)
        self.stop_button.connect("clicked", self.stop_player)
        self.update_button.connect("clicked", self.update)

        self.draw_area = Gtk.DrawingArea()
        self.draw_area.set_size_request(300,300)

        self.draw_area.connect("realize",self._realized)

        self.hbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=6)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.playback_button, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.stop_button, True, True, 0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.update_button, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        self.add(self.vbox)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.draw_area, True, True, 0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.positioner,True,True,0)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox, False, False, 0)

    def toggle_player_playback(self, widget, data=None):

        """
        Handler for Player's Playback Button (Play/Pause).
        """

        if self.is_player_active == False and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.is_player_active = True

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == True:
            self.player.play()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
            self.player_paused = False

        elif self.is_player_active == True and self.player_paused == False:
            self.player.pause()
            self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)
            self.player_paused = True
        else:
            pass

    def _key_press_event(self,widget,event):
        keyval = event.keyval
        keyval_name = Gdk.keyval_name(keyval)
        state = event.state
        print(keyval_name)
        if  keyval_name == 'space':
            self.toggle_player_playback(self)
        elif keyval_name == 'Tab':
            self.update(self)
        elif keyval_name == "s":
            self.stop_player(self)
        elif keyval_name == "Escape":
            self.close_window()
        elif keyval_name == "f":
            self.toggle_fullscreen(self)
        elif keyval_name == "Up":
            if self.volume < 100:
                self.volume +=1
                print(self.volume)
                self.player.audio_set_volume(self.volume)
        elif keyval_name == "Down":
            if self.volume > 0:
                self.volume -=1
                print(self.volume)
                self.player.audio_set_volume(self.volume)
        else:
            return False
        return True

    def update(self,widget, data=None):
        self.stop_player(self)
        self.src = get_src_of_rand_video()
        self.set_my_media(self.player, self.vlcInstance, self.src)
        self.player.play()

    def toggle_fullscreen(self, widget, data=None):
        if self.isFullscreen == True:
            self.isFullscreen = False
            self.hbox.show()
            self.set_decorated(True)
            self.unmaximize()
            self.unfullscreen()

        elif self.isFullscreen == False: 
            self.isFullscreen = True
            self.set_decorated(False)
            self.hbox.hide()
            self.maximize()
            self.fullscreen()

    def stop_player(self, widget, data=None):
        self.player.stop()
        self.is_player_active = False
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.play_image)

    def set_my_media(self, _player, _instance, _source):
        _media = _instance.media_new(_source)
        _media.get_mrl
        _player.set_media(_media)
        return _player

    def _realized(self, widget, data=None):
        self.vlcInstance = vlc.Instance("--no-xlib")
        self.src = get_src_of_rand_video()

        self.player = self.vlcInstance.media_player_new()
        # uncomment to use vlc in window
        win_id = widget.get_window().get_xid()
        self.player.set_xwindow(win_id)
        self.player.set_fullscreen(True)
        self.player = self.set_my_media(self.player, self.vlcInstance, self.src)
        self.player.play()
        self.playback_button.set_image(self.pause_image)
        self.is_player_active = True

        #not sure if this is a good place for this loop
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            self.positioner.set_value(self.player.get_position())
            time.sleep(1)

    def close_window():
        self.running = False
        self.destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
        window = ApplicationWindow()
        window.setup_objects_and_events()
        window.show()
        Gtk.main()
        window.player.stop()
        window.vlcInstance.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't work very well for that.

In the future, please provide more details as to why it does not work, so people can help you better.

> the original vlc player does it

FYI, VLC uses Qt.

Listen for [libvlc_MediaPlayerPositionChanged](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__event.html#gga284c010ecde8abca7d3f262392f62fc6a4b6dc42c4bc2b5a29474ade1025c951d) or `libvlc_MediaPlayerTimeChanged` then query the mediaplayer for the value and set it on the UI control (and vice versa for the user to set time).

This will be of interest: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/npapi-vlc/blob/6eae0ffb9cbaf8f6e04423de2ff38daabdf7cae3/npapi/vlcplugin_gtk.cpp#L305

Comment: thanks, the progress bar would be great, but I need to be able to drag it to seek the position in the video . I'm also unsure where to put the loop updating the position in my code. I'll go ahead and post it.

Comment: Edited my answer